# Python 2.7 tkSimpleDialog.Dialog crashes when pressing Enter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I inherited a class from tkSimpleDialog.Dialog. From a tkInter application, I open it, it has some Entry fields, an OK and a Cancel button.

When this dialog is open and I press the Enter button the dialog and also the main application freezes completely and won't do anything further.

I tried to bind <"Return"> event to it, to catch, but nothing else happened, just the freeze.

Sadly I can't attach code, because it is my work in a company.

Does anyone have an idea how could I resolve the problem and maybe set the Enter button to activate th OK?

I use Python 2.7 and cannot use other versions.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
import tkSimpleDialog
from mem_data import *
from collections import namedtuple

class OpenFileDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):
        self.master = master

    def apply(self):
        self.result = "OK"enter code here
```

And I call it like this:

```
d = OpenFileDialog(self.master)
mcu = d.result
```

Comment: Start by creating an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't need (or want!) to see your actual code, we just need to see any code that reproduces the problem.  Most likely the problem is in the code that gets called after the dialog goes away.

Comment: Added some code. It is very simple. If I click OK everything works, if I press Enter everything freezes forever :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `self.master`. Unfortunately, Tkinter uses `self.master` internally. To fix this you need to choose a different variable name.

```
class OpenFileDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        self._master = master
        ...
```